# How to upload file with Web.py+phonegap

Tags: cordova, upload, web.py

I'm using web.py as a RESTful server for my project,and now I'm faced a problem is how to upload file.
In the Phonegap offical document,i found the example ,but it was written by PHP,on the server side it use a function named **move_uploaded_file()**.I thought that is something to get the file and then saving it where the user want.

So,that is my question,is there something like that in web.py.Or how could i get the file with web.py？

i need some help,thanks.

I have worked it out.
On the client side:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";#keep this name the same as server 
        ...
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload", win, fail, options);
    }
```

On the server side:

```
def POST(self):
    files = web.input(file={})#where the client side defined
    data  = files['file'].file.read()#got the data
    ...do something you wanted...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this recipe](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fileupload):

```
import web

urls = ('/upload', 'Upload')

class Upload:
    def GET(self):
        return """<html><head></head><body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body></html>"""

    def POST(self):
        x = web.input(myfile={})
        web.debug(x['myfile'].filename) # This is the filename
        web.debug(x['myfile'].value) # This is the file contents
        web.debug(x['myfile'].file.read()) # Or use a file(-like) object
        raise web.seeother('/upload')


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = web.application(urls, globals()) 
   app.run()
```

Comment: I see this,but on the client side ,there is no form, just can use the phonegap api what's name is filetranser,it send the file to the server .I have tried the above code in server side to got the file contets or file object,but it doesn't work.......